# UIWebView frame to fill screen when loaded landscape and portrait

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am adding a UIWebView to my view, which works fine when I am in portrait.  But when I load that same UIWebView in landscape it does not fill the screen.  I suspect it comes from how I am setting the frame:

```
CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screen.size.width, screen.size.height)];
webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Is there a better way to do this so it will load correctly in both landscape and portrait, and fill the screen when rotated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How sure are you that the parent view is resizing to the full width?  UIWebView subview will not go larger than it's parent...

Comment: maybe set the initial size to be the size of the parent and then set the resizing flags to resize with the parent in both directions.  Not sure what'll happen if you start out larger than the parent (which I think you are).  Might mess up the autoresizing logic.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.. After i Logged the self.view.frame.size.width i was surprised to find out thats it was 320 instead of 480. The solution to this was :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[self.view setBounds:CGRectMake(0.f, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.view setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
[(UIWebView*)myWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];}
```

Seems that the correct size of self.frame is returned just before showing the view :)